# Coaxial connector with a #2-64 thread

Tags: rf, connector, coax

We've been tasked with considering an existing design for coaxial bulkhead connector (breaching a pressure vessel).

One end of the bulkhead has a relatively common 'Microdot' / 'S-50 series' coaxial interface.

The other end has a threaded **#2-64** (ANSI American thread) for the **shield connection**.

I'm looking for **what type of threaded coaxial connector** (like the S-50 or SSMA - but even smaller) that this smaller-end was designed to connect to.

Some likely misleading dimensions that pertain to the center conductor:

- #25 AWG or smaller (0.02" diameter)

  0.037" (1 mm) or smaller center conductor insulator (core) outside-diameter

Yikes, that seems small...

It is also entirely possible that there is no standard-type connector, and that this was an entirely custom contraption (whose history and all relevant documentation was tossed-out with the fax machine).

Sorry, no pictures are available.

Anyone have any good suggestions?

Thank you and best regards,

Chris

Comment: What signal/spectrum/power is being passed?

Comment: @Andyaka Nothing challenging.  DC to ~2 MHz, low-voltage.  Acoustic/Ultrasonic apps.  1:100 duty cycle (low power).

Comment: What kind of pressure, is there an IP rating?

Comment: @VoltageSpike  That's a property of the bulkhead design.  My concern is the connection to it (which is at ambient).  But if you're curious, let's say 10,000 psi /700 bar, up to 30,000 psi @ 150 C to maybe 300 C.

Comment: That is a lot, more than anything I've worked with!

Comment: @VoltageSpike It's a daily occurrence here.  60,000 psi is our typical limit.

Answer (score 1):

I compile lists of connectors. These are the smallest coax connectors I list:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [*Industry standard*](https://www.rosenberger.com/product/rpc-135/) - [1.35mm](https://cdn.everythingrf.com/live/63_291_rpc_1_35_TM_RPC1.35_Flyer_2019_636852039319870968.pdf) (pdf)
- [*Industry standard*](https://www.pasternack.com/1.85mm-connectors-category.aspx) - 1.85mm - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tnprr)
- [*Industry standard*](https://mpd.southwestmicrowave.com/product-category/1-0-mm-w-connectors/) - [1mm](https://www.rosenberger.com/0_documents/de/catalogs/ba_tm/TM_RPC1.00_Flyer_2017.pdf) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tnprz)
- [*Industry standard*](https://www.radiall.com/products/rf-coaxial-connectors/high-frequency-connectors/2-4mm.html) - 2.4mm - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tnpr1)
- [*Industry standard*](https://www.amphenolrf.com/connectors/ssmc-connectors.html) - SSMC - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tnpqw)
- [Southwest Microwave](https://mpd.southwestmicrowave.com/product-category/0-9-mm-supermini/) - 0.9mm
- [TE](https://www.te.com/usa-en/plp/ossm-rf-connectors-osmm/ZnDgY30oBXq2Az9.html) - [OSMM](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1308940_Sec2_threaded&DocType=CS&DocLang=EN) (pdf) - [digikey](https://www.digikey.se/short/4tnjrm)
- Wiltron Anritsu - 0.6 mm
- Wiltron Anritsu - [0.8 mm](https://dl.cdn-anritsu.com/en-us/test-measurement/files/Brochures-Datasheets-Catalogs/datasheet/11410-00317A.pdf) (pdf)

None of them use a ANSI thread. Are you sure your connector has a #2 thread? If it's metric, it could be one of them.

Comment: Absolutely, 100% #2-64 threads.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the list.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: The list is from my [connector identifier utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=classes).